# Error cross compiling linux kernel using buildroot

Tags: compiling, linux-kernel, embedded, gcc, buildroot

I am trying to build a kernel bt in cross compiling the kernel when I ran following command

```
make CROSS_COMPILE=i686-linux- ARCH=x86
```

I got the following error:

```
UCLIB_EXTRA_CFLAGS="" \
install_runtime install_dev
make[1]: /home/abc/Desktop/softwares/buildroot-2012.08-rc1/output/host/usr/bin/x86-unknown-linux-uclibc-gcc: Command not found
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/abc/Desktop/softwares/buildroot-2012.08-rc1/output/toolchain/uClibc-0.9.33.2'
/bin/sh: /home/abc/Desktop/softwares/buildroot-2012.08-rc1/output/host/usr/bin/x86-unknown-linux-uclibc-gcc: not found
make[1]: /home/abc/Desktop/softwares/buildroot-2012.08-rc1/output/host/usr/bin/x86-unknown-linux-uclibc-gcc: Command not found
make[1]: /home/abcDesktop/softwares/buildroot-2012.08-rc1/output/host/usr/bin/x86-unknown-linux-uclibc-gcc: Command not found
make[1]: Circular libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/i386/gen_tcb-offsets.s <- libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/i386/tcb-offsets.h dependency dropped.
CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/gen_pthread-pi-defines.s
/bin/sh: /home/abc/Desktop/softwares/buildroot-2012.08-rc1/output/host/usr/bin/x86-unknown-linux-uclibc-gcc: not found
make[1]: *** [libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/gen_pthread-pi-defines.s] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/abc/Desktop/softwares/buildroot-2012.08-rc1/output/toolchain/uClibc-0.9.33.2'
make: *** [/home/abc/Desktop/softwares/buildroot-2012.08-rc1/output/host/usr/x86-unknown-linux-uclibc/sysroot/usr/lib/libc.a] Error 2
```

Any suggestions?